# WSO2 IS - add user in role with self provisionning

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're currently working with WSO2 IS server, version 5.7.0. At this time, everything seems to be ok excepting one thing.

We activated self-provisionning and we added a "Service provider" with oauth2 authentication enabled.

It created the role named "Application/myapp".

Then, going on the "authorize" form, we press "Register now" button and we can create a user. It sends validation mail, and the user is created.

But, the user is **not** assigned to Application/myapp role.

Is there something we can do to assign user role at registration time ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you configure role-mapping in Identity Provider?

Comment: I tried but it seems that didn't changed anything.

Comment: Did you try adding claim mapping to map claim coming from identity provider claim URI to Local claim URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have confused. The register now will be redirected to the self sign up form. The users created there will be automatically assigned to the 'Internal/selfsignup' role.

There is no link with the created application and the self sign up process. The automatically created application role (Application/myapp) is for a different requirement. The users with that application role can perform the update and delete operations of the application.

> Is there something we can do to assign user role at registration time?

No, you can't create a role. If you want to have this functionality, we need to have your own self sign up for the application and send the user registration request to the IS using SCIM. [Here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#UsersEndpoint#createUser) you can find the API definitions. You can use the oAuth tokens to access these APIs.

Comment: And you can disable the  "Register now" link from the log in form . There is a configuration in the resident identity provider